# How can I use/import the @EnableRedisHttpSession Spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to follow the Spring tutorial at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-redis.html.
I add the listed dependencies but the @EnableRedisHttpSession cannot be resolved to a type.

I'm new to Spring, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I do see this annotation exists in the api docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.html.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtest1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>adamspringtest1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my Config.java :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;

@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(); 
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And remove:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Basically, you should put `<type>pom</type>` dependencies in `<dependencyManagement>` section of `pom.xml`. Also, you don't need version as you use `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

In addition, to enable Spring Boot auto-configuration, use `@EnableRedisHttpSession` on the class also annotated with `@Configuration`, or alternatively add it together with your `@SpringBootApplication`. So, for example you should have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work.  (after I imported the suggested import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession)  I'm surprised the guide on spring.io shows deps that don't seem to work.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First shot i would say, would be the missing "@Configuration" on your configuration class. That's the clear difference i see between your Config.class and the example in the documentation. Maybe try this first and if the problem persists at least you'll have a exception to show here. :D

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually already had/tried that @Configuration annotation on there and it didn't seem make a difference.. then pulled it out since the */java-redis.html link above didn't have that in there.

Comment: I can't properly test your build right now, but from past tests i can assure @Configuration always makes a difference when you're explicitly declaring configuration classes under Spring.
Helped me a lot: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-configuration-annotation/

Sorry for not addressing the problem root at first.

Comment: Thanks for looking.  Zgurskyi's answer seemed to work, but thanks for the link.  I'll use it as I learn more about Spring.